# Save Transparency Check Box

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, save

I'm working in Photoshop CC. When I go to save my graphic as a tiff the save transparency check box isn't active. What am I doing wrong? How do I make the checkbox active?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but does your file actually have any transparency? That's the only situation I know where it doesn't give you the option (and when you say it isn't active I assume you mean it's greyed out and you can't check the box?).

Comment: Can you please provide a test document? Either that or a screenshot of the layers panel. Far easier to diagnose with a bit more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too obvious a question, but I have been tripped up by this a number of times. Do you have a background layer in your image that is filled with a solid color?  If so, you need to delete that background--otherwise there is no transparency to save.

Comment: No. No colored background layer

Comment: Went back and eliminated the very bottom layer. Seems to have done the trick. Thank you. This is a great resource